# Nautilus cannot move to trash

Tags: ubuntu, file-management, samba, trash

Thing takes place on ubuntu.

I want to move a file to trash. I am not the owner of the file, but file belongs to root:samba, and I am member of samba group, and file permissions are rwxrw-r--

There is message "Cannot move file to trash, do you want to delete immediately?". Nothing more.

Why can't I move it to trash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You are not the owner of the file, so you cannot change it's ownership or group.</strike>

Putting a file in **your** `.Trash` means nautilus will try to change it's ownership and group to your user's uid and gid.

Ultimately I believe it's a bug and should be reported.

#### Edit:

I can't reproduce this, as I recreated the exact same conditions (same user:group and perms) and decided this is NOT a bug but **normal behavior**.

Guessing that you have ownership as `samba`, I guess the file is located in a **remote storage**, and moving items in a *remote* storage (like a Windows share) to *local trash* does not make sense.

Comment: But root can change ownership, can't it? Even if I start nautilus as root (by gksu), still there is the same message.

Comment: if LiraNuna's diagnosed correctly, the permissions issue isn't the problem. the error isn't really accurate; the problem is putting it in the trash.  if you need to delete it, just delete it.  putting it in the trash won't work.

Comment: The Trash folder is only defined for local mounts (i.e. USB disks and such) and your home directory. Trying to trash a file from anywhere else will generally give you this message.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a remote file issue as LiraNuna says.

However, I'm guessing it's simply too big.  The trash can has an upper limit on how much it will hold, and if you're deleting something bigger, Nautilus will think it's too big to keep around on the chance that you might want it back, so it deletes directly instead.